# why entity class doesn't make @sequencegenerator?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have added sequence and trigger in my oracle database, then I created entity classes from database, but it doesn't make @sequencegenerator in entity class. I used netbeans with glassfish server and eclipselink jpa provider. would you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please include the Java code and the SQL you use. And please describe in more detail what "it doesn't make" means.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the @SequenceGenerator in the generated code, it has no idea you want to use the sequence for the table.  In general the generated code is a quick start, you are suppose the customize it to your needs.